# Moq'ing HttpContext.Current

Tags: unit-testing, moq, httpcontext

I have a class library that has a method that sends emails based on a template. I access the template via the following:

```
HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("email template path");
```

Now when it comes to writing my unit tests I want to be able mock out the "Current Context", I have tried to use the MVCMockHelpers but the "Current" property always returns null.

Is it possible to mock this property out? If so how do I go about it?

Answer (score 3):

I'd consider whether you'd be better of removing the dependency on HttpContext entirely and pass the path alone into the method as a string param.

If you're also taking a dependency on HttpContext elsewhere in the same library then you need to take a dependency on HttpContextBase rather than call HttpContext directly.  You should pass this in at the call site or as a constructor injected parameter.

Creating a Mock HttpContext has been covered nicely by many others including [here](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2008/07/10/37824/) by Craig Stuntz.  This will at least get you started but will likely needed modification for your specific testing requirements.

Comment: More specifically, the class should be taking a dependency on something like a path provider class since the reason it is accessing the static Current property is to call the HttpServerUtility MapPath method. If the code is accessing other Current properties then it would need to go up a level and abstract out the HttpContext itself.

Comment: The referenced article create a fake HttpContextBase and not a HttpContext.

Comment: Everywhere I have found that issue in legacy code, it has been trivial to switch to using `HttpContextBase` in consuming code. After that, if you are ever working with the old `HttpContext`, you can simply wrap it with `new HttpContextWrapper(someHttpContext)` and it will then work as an `HttpContextBase`. That said, as Daz/Sixto said, it's definitely worth removing dependencies on any sort of `HttpContext*` in favor of the exact item you need if you can help it.